# Passing private instance properties object around my program

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me why my properties object is null? Do I have to pass it into the method, or is there a better way? What if I need to pass my properties object between packages? Thanks!

```
public class Test {
    private Properties properties = null;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        testObject = new Test();
        Properties properties = new Properties(); // Then load properties from fileInputStream sucessfully

        utilityMethod(); 
    }

    private void utilityMethod() {
        properties.getProperty("test"); // Why do I get a null pointer exception?
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: because you didn't set Test.properties to anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In main(), your assignment to "properties" is to a local variable, not the instance field.

If you'd like to set the field, you can do so like this:

```
private Properties properties = new Properties();
```

Or in a constructor like this:

```
 public Test() {
    properties = new Properties();
 }
```

Or, if you want a single value for all instances of class Test, like this:

```
 private static Properties properties = new Properties();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `Properties properties = new Properties();` you are using another one.So use global  `properties` this time.

```
public class Test {
    private Properties properties = null;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        testObject = new Test();
        properties = new Properties(); // Now you are using global `properties` variable

        utilityMethod(); 
    }

    private void utilityMethod() {
        testObject .properties.getProperty("test"); // access by using testObject  object
    }
}
```

or you can declare it as static like

```
 private static Properties properties = new Properties();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did (I can see), but seen as the OP failed to, it might be more helpful then just throwing the answer at them ;)

Comment: That's not static. I think it would be `testObject.properties` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've redeclared it again within your main...

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    testObject = new Test();
    // This is local variable whose only context is within the main method
    Properties properties = new Properties(); // Then load properties from fileInputStream sucessfully

    utilityMethod(); 
}
```

ps- Your example won't compile, as `utilityMethod` is not `static` and can not be called from the context of the `main` method ;)

Comment: main() is not a constructor.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer From a technical stand point - it does "construct" something ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple typo.

You are creating a local instance of Properties, "Properties properties = new Properties();"

As answered by @PSR, initialize global variable here :)